# ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. - feature engineering

Tags: python, arrays, types, feature-extraction, feature-engineering

I have problem with feature converting, fitting to the model etc. I have a dataset which looks like this:

```
>>>ar
```

```
array([[array([ 5.7055844e-05,  5.6061646e-05,  6.0333405e-06, ...,
       -3.0670577e-05,  1.1646989e-07,  0.0000000e+00], dtype=float32),
        array([1.1998704e-04, 1.6027575e-04, 3.8233120e-06, ..., 3.6795704e-05,
       2.3338929e-05, 7.6700599e-05], dtype=float32),
        array([ 2.9097323e-04, -4.8251706e-05,  2.1321949e-04, ...,
        2.5432950e-04,  6.6656226e-05,  0.0000000e+00], dtype=float32),
        array([ 0.00038439,  0.00024272, -0.00031127, ...,  0.00023522,
        0.00063282,  0.        ], dtype=float32),
        array([0.00088874, 0.00092302, 0.00048189, ..., 0.00122693, 0.00102175,
       0.        ], dtype=float32)],
       [array([ 6.221766e-05,  2.306384e-06, -6.101116e-06, ...,  8.874389e-04,
        5.551182e-04,  0.000000e+00], dtype=float32),
        array([ 7.5782154e-05, -2.6252441e-05,  4.9910428e-05, ...,
        1.9935844e-04,  1.5705503e-03,  3.0954126e-03], dtype=float32),
        array([ 7.5745847e-05, -5.8995029e-05, -6.2226703e-05, ...,
       -2.1493966e-03,  2.2877045e-03,  0.0000000e+00], dtype=float32),
        array([-1.5509137e-04, -1.5936996e-04, -7.3279851e-05, ...,
       -2.4918776e-02,  1.2001377e-03,  0.0000000e+00], dtype=float32),
        array([-2.50132987e-04, -5.18614776e-04, -2.32997467e-04, -3.67275206e-05,
        1.26585364e-05,  1.10550085e-04, -5.04464842e-05,  3.20263207e-05,
       -7.98436813e-05, -2.09790422e-04,  1.78190414e-04, -4.01495723e-04,
       -2.13102205e-04, -7.10734166e-05,  4.74034110e-04,  4.26594401e-04,
       -1.75702153e-04, -1.28350221e-05,  2.16045813e-03, -3.84856714e-04,
       -2.80865468e-04,  2.75549944e-04, -1.46771781e-05,  8.44351016e-05,
       -2.06105853e-03, -1.06880441e-03,  7.09715066e-04,  4.02938109e-04,
       -3.59986676e-04, -5.27394935e-04,  1.58879929e-03, -1.15756760e-03,
       -6.70766924e-04,  1.85540272e-03, -1.23383524e-03, -1.61758857e-03,
        8.97027086e-04,  2.96453480e-03, -1.93061261e-03, -1.36286998e-03,
        2.07643025e-04, -1.38311274e-03, -9.42107290e-04,  5.81716187e-04,
        1.24940649e-04,  1.19656511e-03, -5.85947186e-04,  5.97115606e-04,
        3.20665073e-03, -2.12744903e-03,  6.97748736e-04, -5.02344035e-03,
        1.64076407e-03, -2.22343951e-05,  2.18477193e-03, -3.46983876e-03,
        4.66891099e-04, -7.34810717e-04,  1.19082211e-03,  8.16369429e-04,
       -2.84807221e-03,  2.44068913e-04, -1.13273179e-03, -1.73118152e-03,
       -2.63306731e-03,  5.17322682e-04,  2.43354402e-03, -1.50706945e-03,
        2.70615658e-03, -4.34206612e-03,  2.07528193e-03, -4.25983965e-03,
       -4.61783493e-03,  2.00988445e-03, -3.05252383e-03,  1.80061348e-03,
       -5.97684644e-04, -2.36076629e-03, -1.60181243e-03, -1.21151935e-03,
        2.58965930e-03, -6.70618378e-04,  4.80818283e-03, -1.03705702e-03,
       -1.69692608e-03,  4.74952161e-03, -3.20402998e-03, -2.11519655e-04,
        8.73757992e-04, -7.50378706e-04,  3.99773940e-03, -4.07008594e-03,
       -6.36700867e-03, -1.78676983e-03,  2.31163530e-03, -2.91620195e-03,
       -5.08897938e-04,  2.04263069e-03, -5.44865616e-03, -4.39436641e-03,
       -1.55351916e-03,  1.68799097e-03,  8.42185505e-03, -2.79698242e-03,
       -5.69193624e-03,  1.53655023e-03,  3.26884910e-04,  4.20178706e-03,
        2.69798562e-04, -4.63740854e-03, -1.25751318e-03, -4.05798806e-03,
        3.68853379e-03,  3.29690846e-03,  5.80451312e-03, -1.97532251e-02,
        3.26196514e-02,  8.89291242e-03, -2.96750776e-02,  3.95461060e-02,
       -6.36415407e-02,  5.76118901e-02,  4.04214486e-02, -9.31732729e-02,
        6.90592825e-02, -1.66388407e-01,  6.04402423e-02,  1.71747953e-01,
        4.82762009e-02, -6.87708035e-02, -3.24255288e-01,  6.98793530e-02,
        3.68833065e-01,  4.13520895e-02, -3.20972711e-01, -1.74792647e-01,
        1.87005356e-01,  3.08820248e-01, -1.34279609e-01, -3.03122699e-01,
        9.09794420e-02,  2.43173495e-01,  5.92027083e-02, -3.25963020e-01,
       -1.12798467e-01,  3.04347306e-01,  1.43519044e-01, -1.71004295e-01,
       -1.91612780e-01,  9.82110128e-02,  2.39094287e-01, -9.22856331e-02,
       -2.26304114e-01,  4.54166122e-02,  2.07063109e-01,  6.92462921e-02,
       -2.48372674e-01, -1.58505291e-01,  2.36576185e-01,  1.97758794e-01,
       -1.06824934e-01, -2.76523232e-01,  1.59712583e-02,  3.07025552e-01,
        2.78337467e-02, -2.65395224e-01, -1.19488716e-01,  2.22233802e-01,
        2.51534253e-01, -2.10806549e-01, -3.07786852e-01,  1.06267899e-01,
        3.32488060e-01,  9.97030139e-02, -3.87911439e-01, -2.01119781e-01,
        3.45937312e-01,  2.62961626e-01, -2.06056654e-01, -4.02794898e-01,
        1.32920593e-01,  4.81180549e-01, -8.11720341e-02, -4.55816567e-01,
        4.08410057e-02,  4.80263859e-01,  8.62587094e-02, -5.59149921e-01,
       -7.56996796e-02,  5.44718862e-01,  1.63853914e-02, -5.19803643e-01,
       -8.96439999e-02,  4.72155362e-01,  7.06427246e-02, -5.85692346e-01,
       -5.55855036e-03,  5.14727890e-01, -1.21071704e-01, -4.18954551e-01,
        9.73793790e-02,  3.89468312e-01, -4.47207466e-02, -3.41185898e-01,
        1.45066440e-01,  2.76421964e-01, -1.28082991e-01, -1.62615255e-01,
       -2.03464143e-02,  1.35972962e-01,  6.59554601e-02, -1.65605530e-01,
       -3.10047809e-02,  8.92451033e-02,  8.29221830e-02, -7.91712431e-04,
       -1.38988763e-01,  2.97930576e-02,  6.59307688e-02, -1.76024660e-02,
       -1.09338593e-02, -7.74183273e-02,  8.04429576e-02,  9.60687175e-02,
       -8.09503272e-02, -4.87862267e-02, -5.00678495e-02,  8.69722664e-02,
        8.67679566e-02, -1.00398287e-01, -1.28418123e-02,  2.89395452e-03,
        5.11983447e-02,  3.69246975e-02, -1.21176258e-01,  1.59684103e-02,
        3.37051377e-02,  4.15580012e-02,  3.32168825e-02, -1.13420740e-01,
        2.27177851e-02,  2.77516264e-02,  8.81370157e-03,  3.42645161e-02,
       -9.46949273e-02,  4.01373617e-02,  3.19624506e-02, -2.56682858e-02,
        3.11362892e-02, -6.92124143e-02,  4.36176583e-02,  3.63851935e-02,
       -5.84320650e-02,  2.71467548e-02, -2.99443714e-02,  2.09636781e-02,
        4.54063565e-02, -7.01520741e-02,  1.24164559e-02,  4.01133411e-02,
       -3.42765450e-02,  1.67909078e-02,  2.69384310e-03, -1.90617442e-02,
        3.45125012e-02, -1.68765392e-02, -2.81561352e-02,  4.22924533e-02,
       -2.35432759e-02, -2.26264764e-02,  4.21712212e-02, -2.90238485e-02,
       -2.25337110e-02,  4.48567979e-02, -2.77324021e-02, -2.41328366e-02,
        4.12657447e-02, -2.27341354e-02, -2.18422785e-02,  3.53548340e-02,
       -1.71523653e-02, -1.89882126e-02,  2.85824873e-02, -6.79139979e-03,
       -1.70115139e-02,  2.22209655e-02,  3.93654965e-03, -1.49501357e-02,
        1.42174587e-02,  1.18631050e-02, -1.64353009e-02,  9.05312039e-03,
        1.69982351e-02, -2.00802200e-02,  3.33764032e-03,  1.88018195e-02,
       -2.35136170e-02, -4.61934321e-03,  1.24956146e-02, -1.38690770e-02,
        9.09462944e-03, -2.82146819e-02,  2.75201611e-02,  6.26248047e-02,
       -1.01863362e-01,  1.81588884e-02,  1.57127216e-01, -8.58612284e-02,
       -1.46573275e-01,  7.87563175e-02,  1.71205059e-01, -7.79722854e-02,
       -2.90408760e-01,  1.35055631e-01,  3.71433586e-01, -1.70644894e-01,
       -3.58784139e-01,  1.78652942e-01,  3.55965972e-01, -9.95914340e-02,
       -4.28143322e-01,  7.95025602e-02,  4.17419642e-01, -9.81241390e-02,
       -3.72594714e-01,  1.35789871e-01,  3.36555243e-01, -6.46241009e-02,
       -3.75851452e-01,  6.86504319e-02,  3.30352008e-01, -1.45331591e-01,
       -3.02477956e-01,  2.25232974e-01,  2.55260646e-01, -1.72101319e-01,
       -2.67332375e-01,  2.15480089e-01,  2.34768257e-01, -3.21559787e-01,
       -1.77751005e-01,  3.57985348e-01,  8.12360048e-02, -3.49699885e-01,
        4.62088585e-02,  2.96821952e-01, -3.62597480e-02, -3.73856962e-01,
        2.07650796e-01,  2.85638869e-01, -3.07367265e-01, -1.38422057e-01,
        3.16929817e-01,  3.29055712e-02, -3.05851638e-01,  4.18581367e-02,
        2.07307860e-01, -3.65078114e-02, -2.08954334e-01,  1.15835510e-01,
        1.89271718e-01, -1.35286346e-01, -1.14638656e-01,  7.95663893e-02,
        5.47437221e-02, -6.44240528e-02, -1.07573435e-01,  1.13167986e-01,
        1.28206640e-01, -1.30099058e-01, -1.16184503e-02,  1.20276898e-01,
       -3.81765701e-02, -7.90693164e-02, -2.70698480e-02,  4.51746248e-02,
        1.92476250e-02, -1.18132599e-01,  3.86589617e-02,  1.16285101e-01,
       -9.48260278e-02, -1.96106099e-02,  1.01828828e-01, -1.97098553e-02,
       -3.74629684e-02,  4.52632830e-03,  3.04706730e-02,  9.91918612e-03,
       -8.85911658e-02,  3.57341580e-02,  7.91888759e-02, -1.18861064e-01,
        5.57882525e-03,  1.15653321e-01, -8.74212310e-02, -2.68238895e-02,
        9.43355635e-02, -2.69919820e-02, -3.36415134e-02,  1.66471377e-02,
        2.62455866e-02, -4.70935926e-03, -7.45785683e-02,  4.11548913e-02,
        5.44777364e-02, -1.31257221e-01,  2.53099538e-02,  1.14924289e-01,
       -1.21428080e-01, -6.02243654e-03,  1.38502017e-01, -6.38436377e-02,
       -3.50241177e-02,  9.00848061e-02,  5.49124554e-03, -4.80630361e-02,
       -2.56355666e-02,  4.47334275e-02, -1.05943549e-02, -1.42408222e-01,
        5.15210666e-02,  1.06665924e-01, -1.47660673e-01,  4.01523896e-02,
        2.12673858e-01, -7.71741420e-02, -6.12733811e-02,  1.06302977e-01,
       -2.54376754e-02, -1.54603511e-01, -5.85459322e-02,  1.23146340e-01,
        1.47082470e-02, -1.59586176e-01,  1.47223681e-01,  1.78414449e-01,
       -2.35620543e-01, -3.10197994e-02,  2.50577182e-01, -9.22670215e-02,
       -2.04145253e-01,  1.01743147e-01,  1.51013002e-01, -1.27020359e-01,
       -1.80627212e-01,  2.27126539e-01,  1.75529256e-01, -3.49577248e-01,
        1.19479168e-02,  3.36663306e-01, -1.14458546e-01, -3.34890902e-01,
        2.63799191e-01,  1.90024987e-01, -2.59989381e-01, -1.77681863e-01,
        3.57965052e-01,  9.86060947e-02, -4.61537898e-01,  1.51881099e-01,
        3.79338920e-01, -2.90652841e-01, -2.89060533e-01,  4.20831829e-01,
        6.37636110e-02, -3.85212660e-01,  4.79663610e-02,  3.50061893e-01,
       -9.81782079e-02, -3.88700813e-01,  2.86294639e-01,  2.80561119e-01,
       -3.79774988e-01, -1.42223477e-01,  4.28902745e-01, -2.82620713e-02,
       -3.73153985e-01,  8.93370360e-02,  3.19045305e-01, -8.22907835e-02,
       -3.74681771e-01,  2.21326083e-01,  3.21783841e-01, -2.89963096e-01,
       -2.35971898e-01,  3.17775846e-01,  1.28704518e-01, -2.71582037e-01,
       -1.77587494e-01,  3.20715845e-01,  1.49257019e-01, -3.48330438e-01,
       -5.70387840e-02,  3.54006708e-01, -3.04521918e-02, -2.89206982e-01,
       -3.06792483e-02,  2.86907792e-01,  4.25948277e-02, -3.08825016e-01,
        3.77964452e-02,  2.98367262e-01, -8.39169398e-02, -2.36414492e-01,
       -4.19931859e-03,  2.34851360e-01,  4.31912169e-02, -2.64063776e-01,
        1.48633253e-02,  2.35992059e-01, -3.64842303e-02, -1.78246185e-01,
       -6.52465373e-02,  2.08983392e-01,  1.12416089e-01, -2.34710529e-01,
       -5.67927137e-02,  1.67665467e-01,  4.70459796e-02, -1.10919714e-01,
       -1.37815878e-01,  1.62458807e-01,  1.77372426e-01, -1.91093802e-01,
       -1.13680512e-01,  1.13307036e-01,  9.64792371e-02, -5.02633750e-02,
       -1.65690750e-01,  1.04709432e-01,  1.81614995e-01, -1.30444825e-01,
       -1.26747698e-01,  4.70735095e-02,  1.27897695e-01, -7.61384517e-03,
       -1.73154697e-01,  7.45474994e-02,  1.53680682e-01, -1.03953719e-01,
       -9.28261280e-02,  1.92759521e-02,  1.02114186e-01,  6.72803354e-03,
       -1.47300750e-01,  7.83751830e-02,  1.23279296e-01, -1.22445837e-01,
       -5.02858534e-02,  5.72169200e-02,  3.35517973e-02, -2.16374937e-02,
       -7.38574266e-02,  7.66656846e-02,  8.50839391e-02, -1.29432052e-01,
        6.73087873e-03,  9.69599634e-02, -7.41875917e-02, -1.62758771e-02,
        1.41532682e-02,  9.95931774e-03,  1.72637273e-02, -4.30863388e-02,
        1.28485970e-02,  4.48457710e-02, -4.29849997e-02, -2.00955663e-02,
        3.78854237e-02, -7.12108240e-03, -3.66795957e-02,  2.77334750e-02,
        7.01829419e-03, -3.28536257e-02,  1.06194019e-02,  2.60431804e-02,
       -3.27940844e-02,  5.30336052e-04,  3.88725251e-02, -2.76457854e-02,
       -6.90926332e-03,  2.03364845e-02,  3.39075923e-05, -1.65344309e-02,
       -7.43561983e-03,  3.39616798e-02, -2.16742828e-02, -1.35959387e-02,
        2.40523033e-02,  7.60173798e-03, -2.12635901e-02, -1.24368062e-02,
        3.83661427e-02, -1.78688932e-02, -1.57636795e-02, -1.96550414e-03,
        3.53541672e-02, -2.05903277e-02, -2.09710989e-02,  1.60862952e-02,
        2.68130824e-02, -2.42274478e-02, -2.06072163e-02,  2.70939320e-02,
        1.78762749e-02, -2.62652058e-02, -1.47490688e-02,  2.62378734e-02,
        1.74427014e-02, -2.72660442e-02, -1.16523486e-02,  2.18352843e-02,
        1.91844087e-02, -2.54294984e-02, -1.09813483e-02,  1.41753731e-02,
        2.07868051e-02, -1.85298640e-02, -1.31431762e-02,  3.19644064e-03,
        2.00230144e-02, -8.18382949e-04, -1.83526725e-02, -3.85364145e-03,
        1.39321564e-02,  1.74905844e-02, -2.29938179e-02, -1.33844493e-02,
        1.04319956e-02,  2.18230672e-02, -9.47425328e-03, -2.24713329e-02,
        5.67306578e-03,  1.95557773e-02,  4.95419279e-03, -2.78212968e-02,
       -9.56859440e-05,  1.55225713e-02,  5.89565374e-03, -1.27364174e-02,
       -1.47749539e-02,  1.81296095e-02,  5.58293704e-03, -7.68110668e-03,
       -1.09084044e-02,  9.66903102e-03,  7.53980549e-03, -9.10481345e-03,
       -2.74641067e-03,  6.10562926e-03,  5.04379813e-03, -8.95598438e-03,
        2.18595006e-03,  5.13797067e-03,  2.01915624e-03, -6.37395633e-03,
        3.81602440e-04,  5.53910434e-03,  7.58023001e-04, -3.49271251e-03,
       -2.56337691e-03,  4.70638508e-03,  1.91259291e-03, -2.54368968e-03,
       -3.12441285e-03,  2.82474561e-04,  3.82030895e-03, -2.29130033e-04,
       -3.34824808e-03, -2.64826696e-03,  3.02031729e-03,  2.16916925e-03,
       -2.46565347e-03, -3.20255128e-03,  8.85390677e-04,  2.84469454e-03,
       -6.40249578e-04, -2.94933515e-03,  4.12538648e-05,  2.10767635e-03,
        9.13976692e-06, -1.11455983e-03, -2.30589882e-04,  1.19345146e-03,
        2.59485096e-04, -6.63688872e-04,  4.95602144e-04,  9.58128134e-04,
        3.46386252e-04, -1.36222050e-04,  7.16605282e-04,  1.13731471e-03,
        4.50169202e-04, -3.92968534e-04,  1.86403748e-04,  9.41175502e-04,
        5.59707172e-04, -3.00083775e-04, -2.67655123e-04,  6.44969288e-04,
        4.70684841e-04, -4.27892897e-04, -6.00099098e-04, -5.20278700e-05,
        3.01292166e-04, -2.94676982e-04, -6.63784798e-04, -1.32638030e-04,
       -1.34743750e-05, -4.06252220e-04, -5.34208491e-04, -1.90931838e-04,
       -1.93367247e-04, -2.06703204e-04, -5.38441527e-04, -3.46992485e-04,
       -1.96244655e-05, -1.63836608e-04, -3.93724709e-04, -2.29157740e-04,
        8.84550391e-05,  2.01294664e-04,  1.41236233e-05, -1.59604708e-04,
        2.15548673e-04,  2.05652206e-04, -1.87302940e-05, -7.56068039e-05,
        1.55997754e-04,  1.00156438e-04,  2.74268736e-04, -1.66838727e-05,
       -1.08582317e-05,  3.42336803e-04,  3.40176222e-04,  1.54188601e-04,
        1.21165998e-04,  1.58129726e-04,  1.68211758e-04, -1.29489461e-04,
       -2.89132586e-04,  6.16820180e-04,  1.70151354e-03, -4.87212604e-03,
        2.74286326e-03,  5.35220699e-03, -8.43043625e-03, -1.01415785e-02,
        1.59885436e-02,  1.13095902e-03, -4.66894098e-02,  7.03729168e-02,
        3.34319053e-03, -9.57680419e-02, -1.59220323e-02,  1.09947830e-01,
        7.11229593e-02, -3.58904600e-01, -3.69460136e-03,  4.89240706e-01,
        4.90924120e-02, -4.85584021e-01, -2.78164834e-01,  4.12281632e-01,
        5.14802694e-01, -3.31587344e-01, -5.41774273e-01,  9.10323858e-03,
        5.19363999e-01,  3.57275188e-01, -4.36252058e-01, -4.65620637e-01,
        5.02262563e-02,  4.40343499e-01,  3.53619635e-01, -3.12587500e-01,
       -3.94003659e-01, -8.78144652e-02,  2.50980467e-01,  3.90533090e-01,
       -6.31056651e-02, -2.31298670e-01, -2.65447259e-01, -4.76351902e-02,
        3.65314364e-01,  2.55368143e-01,  8.58777016e-03, -4.20851946e-01,
       -3.66756976e-01,  2.01073870e-01,  4.78396237e-01,  2.83781171e-01,
       -3.93180221e-01, -4.19858813e-01, -2.80227810e-02,  2.61591643e-01,
        3.59690547e-01, -6.40446469e-02, -1.19570307e-01, -2.42100045e-01,
       -2.07487717e-01,  2.33514071e-01,  3.72156620e-01,  2.28153795e-01,
       -4.31890517e-01, -4.87475753e-01,  1.05005726e-01,  4.87092972e-01,
        3.38898450e-01, -3.80175859e-01, -3.22143316e-01, -3.19261327e-02,
        1.16181143e-01,  2.51768678e-01,  4.65056151e-02,  4.53643054e-02,
       -2.41126671e-01, -2.90730506e-01,  1.70236871e-01,  3.56460333e-01,
        1.91676840e-01, -3.54640752e-01, -3.80391777e-01,  1.44317627e-01,
        4.06718791e-01,  1.67589664e-01, -3.63002002e-01, -3.34372342e-01,
        1.80623770e-01,  3.44499975e-01,  5.18484674e-02, -2.78598517e-01,
       -2.13224366e-01,  2.45986164e-01,  1.15060672e-01, -1.08700700e-01,
       -8.81369337e-02,  8.58035088e-02,  2.47009814e-01, -2.83071846e-01,
       -2.55309820e-01,  1.33974463e-01,  3.84094119e-01, -1.13175437e-02,
       -2.66143799e-01, -1.11288317e-01,  3.35606217e-01, -1.83043182e-01,
       -2.35784337e-01,  1.11144632e-01,  3.73047233e-01, -1.20277345e-01,
       -1.60307288e-01,  1.04500294e-01,  2.04565346e-01, -3.19967806e-01,
       -1.86961561e-01,  3.47917080e-01, -1.58922791e-01, -2.12440103e-01,
        1.79127514e-01,  1.46503419e-01, -2.09161088e-01,  2.46080756e-03,
        3.05247426e-01, -1.47082299e-01, -7.01310113e-02,  3.03469241e-01,
       -1.02985322e-01, -7.94599652e-02,  2.69730955e-01, -8.71004015e-02,
       -7.12842569e-02,  2.55349547e-01, -8.83339047e-02, -6.51006773e-02,
        2.53776252e-01, -1.12363242e-01, -3.61180380e-02,  2.36644238e-01,
       -1.29130706e-01,  2.46424153e-02,  1.35865152e-01, -1.15725011e-01,
        1.19795322e-01, -6.03950098e-02, -8.42271820e-02,  1.85780108e-01,
       -1.84036911e-01, -1.98314488e-02,  6.71563819e-02, -6.60663098e-02,
        1.06482908e-01, -9.33128148e-02,  5.65560758e-02, -3.71348672e-03,
       -2.18284521e-02,  5.46129011e-02, -1.14737280e-01,  7.53072724e-02,
       -7.64911845e-02,  1.00090146e-01, -2.58879159e-02, -1.02492645e-02,
        2.63913851e-02, -6.64609596e-02,  6.57779872e-02, -7.56568760e-02,
        7.44858608e-02, -7.74327740e-02,  5.60361966e-02, -3.00005041e-02,
        5.30178472e-02, -3.54754627e-02,  0.00000000e+00], dtype=float32)],
       [array([0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, ..., 3.3131469e-06,
       6.6249586e-06, 0.0000000e+00], dtype=float32),
        array([0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, ..., 5.227822e-07,
       1.538771e-05, 0.000000e+00], dtype=float32),
        array([ 0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00, ...,
       -2.6937883e-07,  5.3038940e-07,  1.2766583e-06], dtype=float32),
        array([ 0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00, ...,
       -3.8248795e-06,  2.3548841e-07,  0.0000000e+00], dtype=float32),
        array([ 0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00, ...,
       -7.2961164e-08,  3.0179503e-06,  0.0000000e+00], dtype=float32)],
       ...,
       [array([0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, 0.0000000e+00, ..., 1.2345799e-08,
       2.4837327e-08, 1.3832377e-08], dtype=float32),
        array([ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, ...,
       -2.82872570e-09, -2.77558443e-09, -1.09714655e-08], dtype=float32),
        array([ 0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00, ...,
        3.7241577e-08, -4.1676298e-09, -1.2728313e-08], dtype=float32),
        array([0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, 0.000000e+00, ..., 9.838445e-06,
       3.879914e-08, 0.000000e+00], dtype=float32),
        array([ 0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00,  0.0000000e+00, ...,
       -7.0064502e-06, -1.9722158e-05, -6.1301275e-09], dtype=float32)],
       [array([ 2.5779937e-04,  1.0548392e-06, -6.6729594e-04, ...,
       -1.6059866e-04, -6.7526591e-05, -1.9883277e-04], dtype=float32),
        array([ 6.1620097e-04, -2.2158129e-05, -1.0513534e-03, ...,
       -1.4909299e-04, -3.9609952e-04, -4.4965284e-04], dtype=float32),
        array([-2.7274038e-04, -1.1073833e-05, -4.9665722e-04, ...,
       -1.1076126e-03, -1.1109968e-03, -8.4117200e-04], dtype=float32),
        array([ 1.2765429e-04, -3.7662860e-05, -8.3870196e-05, ...,
       -2.7233390e-03, -3.5623512e-03, -2.5052326e-03], dtype=float32),
        array([ 0.00020289, -0.00021641,  0.0001531 , ...,  0.00870614,
       -0.00944865,  0.        ], dtype=float32)],
       [array([7.25149512e-05, 2.05900105e-05, 1.46045295e-05, ...,
       7.75771186e-05, 2.18211499e-05, 2.15153545e-04], dtype=float32),
        array([ 1.5750047e-05,  1.6520382e-05,  5.6520566e-06, ...,
       -2.4987152e-05,  3.5073876e-04,  2.9498199e-04], dtype=float32),
        array([-2.0367588e-05, -3.3011729e-05, -2.6642403e-05, ...,
       -4.0776699e-04, -2.0840520e-04,  3.5939045e-04], dtype=float32),
        array([-1.7277009e-04, -1.5671067e-04, -1.3649010e-04, ...,
       -6.7962799e-05, -1.1087395e-03,  0.0000000e+00], dtype=float32),
        array([-0.00048375, -0.00034697, -0.00032095, ...,  0.00035163,
       -0.0002359 ,  0.        ], dtype=float32)]], dtype=object)
```

As you see each array element consists of another array with float elements. The shape of that whole array is (5252, 5). I want that to manipulate that data for example fitting model, concatenate to another array, but when I'm trying it:

```
def calculate_statistics(list_values):
    n5 = np.nanpercentile(list_values, 5)
    n25 = np.nanpercentile(list_values, 25)
    n75 = np.nanpercentile(list_values, 75)
    n95 = np.nanpercentile(list_values, 95)
    median = np.nanpercentile(list_values, 50)
    mean = np.nanmean(list_values)
    std = np.nanstd(list_values)
    var = np.nanvar(list_values)
    rms = np.nanmean(np.sqrt(list_values**2))
    return [n5, n25, n75, n95, median, mean, std, var, rms]

def calculate_crossings(list_values):
    zero_crossing_indices = np.nonzero(np.diff(np.array(list_values) > 0))[0]
    no_zero_crossings = len(zero_crossing_indices)
    mean_crossing_indices = np.nonzero(np.diff(np.array(list_values) > np.nanmean(list_values)))[0]
    no_mean_crossings = len(mean_crossing_indices)
    return [no_zero_crossings, no_mean_crossings]

def get_features(list_values):
    #entropy = calculate_entropy(list_values)
    crossings = calculate_crossings(list_values)
    statistics = calculate_statistics(list_values)
    return statistics +crossings

def convert(array1, array2):
    for x in range (0, array1.shape[0]):
        for y in range (0, array2.shape[1]):
            array2[x][y] = get_features(array1[x][y])

ar_ed = np.zeros((5252, 5), dtype=float)

convert(ar, ar_ed)
```

"ar" is elaborated array, ar_ed is target array which should be possible to fit in model. I have an error:

```
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-23e774aa76cb> in <module>
----> 1 convert(ar, ar_ed)

<ipython-input-59-661bbbd7b7c2> in convert(array1, array2)
      2     for x in range (0, 5):
      3         for y in range (0, 5):
----> 4             array2[x][y] = get_features(array1[x][y])

ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I know what I did wrong. Before all the operations I convert again my dataset to numpy array, so functions and the rest could work on data because they weren't a list.